# passing pointer to a reading pointer of a string to a function parameter

Tags: c

I'm currently working on "split" function, which takes a string and a separator character, and returns an array of split strings. It's prototype looks like this:

```
char **split(char *str, char sep);
```

and my implementation of the function looks like this:

```
char **split(char *str, char sep);
{
    char **result_array; //array to return
    size_t word_count; //number of words(pieces separated by a separator) in a given string 
    char *ptr; //something i called reading pointer(sorry i don't know any appropriate word to call this), which indicates current reading position from the string 

    ...some trivial codes...

    while (i < word_count)
    {
        jump_to_next_word(&ptr, sep); //change value of a variable 'ptr', to the first byte of the next word
        result_array[i] = make_piece(&ptr, sep); //return word, and change the value of a variable 'ptr', to the next byte of the end of the word
        i += 1;
    }
    result_array[i] = 0; //null-terminating the array
    return result_array;
}
```

so my question is, is it ok to write such a function like 'make_piece' there? I think such function is not good in terms of 'clean code', because one who reads this code cannot know that the function 'make_piece' change the value of the variable 'ptr', by only reading the name of the function.
I have considered several solutions, but not really satisfied.

1. change function name 'make_piece' to something like 'make_piece_and_jump_to_next_separator'.
2. make the function to return ptr, like this:

```
ptr = jump_to_next_word(ptr, sep);
ptr = make_piece(result_array[i], sep);
```

it looks slightly better, but i think it is same that one who reads this code cannot know the the function 'make_piece' changed the value of 'ptr'.

3. make the function to return the length of a word, like this:

```
ptr = jump_to_next_word(ptr, sep);
word_len = make_piece(result_array[i], sep);
ptr += word_len;
```

now the one who reads this code can clearly sees how ptr changes, but it looks somehow verbose, because it needs extra variable only for that purpose, and it makes code longer.
so i'm confused, that which of these options is the most recommended style in practice, or are there any other ways to make this code clean?

Comment: First thing: you can't really return an array from a C function. What you're intending to do here won't work. You can't use an uninitialized array. If you do initialize it, you must initialize it with a specific length *and* commit to releasing the allocation later.

Comment: Look at how [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) works for an example of how C functions do this. In fact, just use `strtok`.

Comment: oh i just omitted malloc() part of the function, because i thought that is obvious. that function works fine, i've tested that, so anything you might think missing here is hiding in ...some trivial codes... part in the function

Comment: Nothing is obvious here. We can't presume anything. Part of problem solving is to assume nothing and question everything. Do you have working code? If so it's off-topic here and needs to go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's also worth noting that functions like this which return allocated arrays are extremely *annoying* as you're placing a lot of responsibility on the calling function where no such responsibility is wanted or necessary. `strtok` does the job without all of this fuss.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i'm totally new on asking questions on stack overflow, i didn't know that i must ask questions like this in code review. thank you for telling me that.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, just pointing out where to go. Hope they can help.